# Problems with sudo in path 

Tags: ubuntu, bash, path, arch-linux

Using:

```
Linux nomemory 2.6.32-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 16 14:17:33 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I have a folder in my `$HOME` called `~/.scriptfarm/scripts` where i keep some of my custom scripts.

```
nomemory@nomemory:~$ ls -l /home/nomemory/.scriptfarm/script
total 20
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nomemory nomemory 10 2010-09-21 01:31 aaa
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nomemory nomemory 31 2010-09-21 00:47 pt.chc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nomemory nomemory 35 2010-09-21 00:47 pt.int
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nomemory nomemory 34 2010-09-21 00:47 pt.rem
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nomemory nomemory 54 2010-09-21 00:47 pt.up
```

The problem is that in Ubuntu none of the scripts are working when prefixed with `sudo`. The behavior is different on Arch, where the scripts are working.

Let me give you an example (`aaa` is a foobar-type script):

```
nomemory@nomemory:~$ aaa
aaa
nomemory@nomemory:~$ sudo aaa
sudo: aaa: command not found
nomemory@nomemory:~$
```

And if a echo $PATH:

```
nomemory@nomemory:~$ sudo echo $PATH
/home/nomemory/.scriptfarm/script:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Do you know why my scripts don't work if I prefix them with `sudo`.
Any solutions ?

**Later edit:**
The work-around I found was to add an alias for sudo: `sudo env PATH=$PATH $@` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test is misleading, because PATH is expanded before calling sudo.  Instead, do:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'
```

and you will see that there is a different path.

To include `/home/nomemory/.scriptfarm/scripts` in your system-wide PATH, you can modify `/etc/profile`:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/nomemory/.scriptfarm/scripts"
```

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks. Do you have any solutions & suggestions how to make work in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu (10.04 at least) there is an option in the `sudoers` file to reset the environment.

```
Defaults    env_reset
```

You can remove it or you should be able to use SETENV on a per-user basis to keep the old environment.

The man page says about `env_reset`:

> If set, sudo will reset the
>   environment to only contain the
>   LOGNAME, SHELL, USER, USERNAME and the
>   SUDO_* variables.  Any variables in
>   the caller's environment that match
>   the env_keep and env_check lists are
>   then added.  The default contents of
>   the env_keep and env_check lists are
>   displayed when sudo is run by root
>   with the -V option.  If the
>   secure_path option is set, its value
>   will be used for the PATH environment
>   variable. This flag is on by default.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is that Ubuntu compiles sudo with the `SECURE_PATH` option, thus making it impossible to pass your PATH environment.  You can see this by specifying the `-V` option when running as root.  Thus the command `sudo sudo -V` dumps a list of defaults.  It appears the only workaround is to recompile sudo.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `which aaa` to find out where aaa is located, then run it from there. Failing that, you may be able to

```
 sudo 'export PATH='$PATH'; aaa'
```

Comment: That gives me an error. Try this: `sudo PATH=$PATH aaa` but it's dependent on `setenv`, `env_reset`, `env_check`, `env_delete`, or `env_keep`, `env_file`, `secure_path` and `secure_path` and possibly others in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: It worked for me, but maybe we have different settings or are using different shells. I much prefer using `which`: there's no need to worry about having $PATH set to `/bin; rm -rf /;`.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute `nomemory` for the name of your user account those files are located in:

`sudo ~nomemory/.scriptfarm/scripts/aaa`

Absolute paths = ♥

Comment: I guess I should also say; `/usr/bin/sudo ~nomemory/.scriptfarm/scripts/aaa`