# Strange PATH when use sudoers via ldap

Tags: ldap, sudo, path

I have a working LDAP authentication environment. LDAP server is on ubuntu 12.04 machine while client are all centos 6.4 machines. Recently I configure sudoers in LDAP following this article http://www.malaya-digital.org/configure-ldap-for-sudo-support-in-ubuntu-server-11-04-64-bit/

Everything works fine except that the PATH is strange when using sudo to execute command.

Here are the PATH of sudo

```
# sudo printenv PATH
"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

It seems that every commands listed in the PATH shown above can be executed, except which in /bin . For example

```
# sudo which node
/usr/local/bin/node

# sudo which zip
/usr/bin/zip

# sudo which ip
/sbin/ip

# sudo which ls
which: no ls in ("/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin") #WTF??

# sudo ls /
sudo: ls: command not found
```

However, when using full path to execute command in /bin, it works.

```
# sudo /bin/ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  NFS  opt  proc  root  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

I have read [Problems with sudo in path](https://serverfault.com/questions/182995/problems-with-sudo-in-path) and [Troubleshooting sudoers via ldap](https://serverfault.com/questions/444219/troubleshooting-sudoers-via-ldap), but find no clue of what's wrong.

The LDAP entry with PATH setting is as follow:

```
dn: cn=defaults,ou=SUDOers,dc=example.dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: sudoRole
cn: defaults
description: Default sudoOption's go here
sudoOrder: 1
sudoOption: env_reset
sudoOption: secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Comment: Related: [Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8646/21471) at Unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to the same problem today and I believe that the solution is simply to remove the double quotes from the `secure_path` option:

```
dn: cn=defaults,ou=SUDOers,dc=example.dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: sudoRole
cn: defaults
description: Default sudoOption's go here
sudoOrder: 1
sudoOption: env_reset
sudoOption: secure_path=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

By surrounding it by quotes, as you can see in the result of `sudo printenv PATH`, the `PATH` contains the quotes themselves.  This seems to correspond to one funny long path, in which directory names contain colons --- not what you want...

Your answer seems to circumvent the problem, probably because the colon at the end has the special meaning of appending some default path.  Try `sudo printenv PATH` to see what's going on --- it did not work in my case.

With the LDIF that I propose above, what you get is the right `PATH`:

```
$ sudo printenv PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: I've run into this problem as well today - this fixed it! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution myself, though I do not know exact why.

It is quite simple, add ":" to the end of the secure_path in LDAP entry fixed all the problem.

```
secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:"
```

Comment: I believe that this answer does not work properly.  The colon at the end may be appending the default path.  I tried it and could not execute anything in `/usr/local/sbin`, which apparently is not in the default path.

Comment: What @nickie said. You might want to change the accepted answer accordingly.